# How to pass multiple records in REST API POST method using JSON body?

Tags: apex, rest-api

```
@RESTResource(urlMapping='/CreateMenu/')
global class CreateRestAPI {
    
    @HTTPPost
    global static String doPost()
    {   
        String ItemName;
        String Price;
        
        String fieldName;
        String fieldValue;
        
        RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
        
        RestResponse res = RestContext.response;       
        
        /*
        String arr = req.requestBody.toString();
        System.debug('Body is '+ arr);
        */
        
        String jsonBody = req.requestBody.toString();
        JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(jsonBody);
        
        
        while(parser.nextToken()!=Null){
            if(parser.getCurrentToken() != JSONToken.END_OBJECT){
                fieldName = parser.getCurrentName();
                fieldValue = parser.getText();
                
                if (fieldName == 'ItemName'){
                    ItemName = fieldValue;
                }
                
                else if (fieldName == 'Price'){
                    Price = fieldValue;
                }
            }
            
        }
        
        Menu__c l = new Menu__c(Item_Name__c = ItemName, Price__c = Decimal.valueOf(Price));
        insert l;
        
        return 'Inserted';
    }
}
```

I want to be able to pass multiple in my workbench json body.

```
{
"records" : [
   {"ItemName":"Burger2", "Price":2}, 
   {"ItemName":"Ice Cream 5", "Price":1}
]}
```

As of now, only Ice Cream 5 is added to the database. How do I ensure that Burger 2 is also added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should prefer [`JSON.deserialize(bodyString, apexType)`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_System_Json.htm#apex_System_Json_deserialize) over JSONParser when possibile.
In order to use it, you should create a class that map the input request:

```java
public class CreateMenuRequest {
    public List<Menu> records;
    
    public class Menu {
        public String ItemName;
        public Decimal Price;
    }
}
```

So right after retrieving `jsonBody` you can leverage `JSON.deserialize()` to obtain a `CreateMenuRequest` instance, then you should to define a list of `Menu__c` and loop over `records` to create the instance of each menu passed via POST and, of course, add them to the list.
After the last iteration you can insert the list of `Menu__c`:

```java
String jsonBody = req.requestBody.toString();
CreateMenuRequest menuRequest = (CreateMenuRequest) JSON.deserialize(body, CreateMenuRequest.class);
List<Menu__c> menusToInsert = new List<Menu__c>();
for (CreateMenuRequest.Menu menu : menuRequest.records) {
    Menu__c record = new Menu__c();
    record.Item_Name__c = menu.ItemName;
    record.Price__c = menu.Price;
    menusToInsert.add(record);
}
insert menusToInsert;
```